# Socket.IO Double Connection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a simple node.js server set up with an angular.js frontent and I am trying to implement Socket.IO so I can live update data on my page but I am running into an issue with double Socket.IO connections opening and hanging my page.

```
var self = this;

self.app = express();
self.http = http.Server(self.app);

self.config = config;

self.io = require('socket.io')(self.http);

self.io.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
});
```

and in my angular.js factory I have

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

If I load up my page on Safari or Chrome on iOS (pretty sure it's happening on Android too but I don't have one to test with, I cannot replicate when I'm not on a mobile device) and refresh the page it will connect correctly and then at random on a page refresh or even sometimes on a new page load I will see in the log that it connected twice at the same time which causes the page to hang on the socket.io request

[image]

and because it hangs on that request the other requests I do will be stuck waiting for that one to complete and the page will never load.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by doing this on the client

```
var socket = io.connect('http://#{ip}:3000',{reconnection:false});
```